# how to create hyperlink by image in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, hyperlink

Usually in php I will call hyperlink by image

```
<a href="siswa/"><img src="image/.png"></a>
```

How about in CI? Maybe use controler or helper?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to try more than this

**In View**

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url() ;?>index.php/ControllerName/MethodName">
    <img src="<?php echo base_url() ;?>path/to/image.png">
</a>
```

Ex

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url() ;?>index.php/home/image">
    <img src="<?php echo base_url() ;?>image/edit.png">
</a>
```

**In Controller** (`home.php`)

```
public function image()
{
    # code...
}
```

> **Note :** - `base_url()` is used to print the Codeigniter project path

Comment: Thanks abdulla i will try

Comment: @AkbarYusrofi enjoy coding